# Compute $\sum_{k=1}^{25} (\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+4})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, telescopic-series

> Compute $\sum_{k=1}^{25} (\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+4})$

I know that some of the terms will cancel each other. Have it been $k+1$ instead of $k+4$, I could have easily see the pattern in which the terms cancel each other. I don't know what would I do if it was say $k+6$ or bigger.

How can I identify the pattern in these type of problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for $0\leq b\leq N$,
$$\sum_{k=1}^{N} (\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+b})=
\sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac{1}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{1}{k+b}=\sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac{1}{k}-\sum_{k=1+b}^{N+b}\frac{1}{k}.$$
Compare the terms in the two sums, what do we obtain after deleting the opposite terms?

Comment: We get $ 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{N+1}-\frac{1}{N+2}-\frac{1}{N+3}-\frac{1}{N+4}$. Thanks

Comment: @EldarRahimli Yes, that's the correct result.

Answer (score 4):

You may write
$$\frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+4} = \left( \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1} \right) + \left( \frac{1}{k+1} - \frac{1}{k+2} \right)+ \left( \frac{1}{k+2} - \frac{1}{k+3} \right) + \left( \frac{1}{k+3} - \frac{1}{k+4} \right)$$

Now, apply telescoping and you get for the sum

$$\left( \frac{1}{1} - \frac{1}{26} \right) + \left( \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{27} \right)+ \left( \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{28} \right) + \left( \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{29} \right)$$

Answer (score 2):

This may help you:
\begin{align}
\require{cancel}
\sum\limits_{k=1}^N \left(\frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+4}\right) &= \sum\limits_{k=1}^N \frac1k - \sum\limits_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{k+4}\\ &= \sum\limits_{k=1}^N \frac1k - \sum\limits_{k=1+4}^{N+4}\frac1k \\&=
\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^4\frac1k + \sum\limits_{k=5}^N\frac1k\right) - \left(\sum\limits_{k=5}^N\frac1k + \sum\limits_{k=N+1}^{N+4}\frac1k\right)\\ &=
\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^4\frac1k + \cancel{\sum\limits_{k=5}^N\frac1k}\right) - \left(\cancel{\sum\limits_{k=5}^N\frac1k} + \sum\limits_{k=N+1}^{N+4}\frac1k\right)\\ &=
\sum\limits_{k=1}^4 \frac1k - \sum\limits_{k=N+1}^{N+4}\frac1k
\end{align}

First split up the sum into two sums. Then change index so that the summand is the same in each. Then realize that a lot of the terms cancel out. Lastly, you're only left with a few terms.

Comment: In this part, $ sum \limits_{k=1}^4 \frac{1}{k} $ , I didn't understand how could we put $4$ instead of $N$

Comment: @EldarRahimli I have added another line to the calculation. Please tell me if you do/don't understand now.

Comment: The idea is that we can split sums into multiple separate sums, like this:

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^N a_k = a_1 + a_2 + ...+ a_{N-1} + a_N = (a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4) + (a_5 + ... + a_{N-1} + a_N) =  \sum\limits_{k=1}^4 a_k + \sum\limits_{k=5}^N a_k $$

Comment: Thanks, got it. I'm grateful

Answer (score 0):

The general term is $\frac 1k -\frac{1}{k+4}$.

The first right term is $\frac 15$, so $1, \frac 12,\frac13,\frac14 $ will not be cancelled on the left.
The last left term is $\frac{1}{25}$, so the terms $\frac{1}{26}, \frac{1}{27}, \frac{1}{28}, \frac{1}{29}$ will not be cancelled on the right. Collate these results.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how those terms from left and right will not be cancelled?

Comment: The first term is $(1-\frac 15)$. The fifth term is $(\frac 15 -\frac 19)$, so the $\frac 15$ is cancelled. However, there is no $"0th"$ term $(\frac 10 - \frac 14)$ to cancel with the fourth term $(\frac14-\frac18)$. So $\frac 14 $ is not cancelled. Same process wih the rest